# PyTorch Temporal Fusion Transformer prediction output length

Tags: python, transformer-model, pytorch-dataloader, pytorch-forecasting

I have trained a temporal fusion transformer on some training data and would like to predict on some unseen data. To do so, I'm using the `pytorch_forecasting` `TimeSeriesDataSet` data structures

`testing = TimeSeriesDataSet.from_dataset(training, df[lambda x: x.year > validation_cutoff], predict=True, stop_randomization=True)`

with

```
df[lambda x: x.year > validation_cutoff].shape
(97036, 13)
```

Given that

```
testing.data['reals'].shape
torch.Size([97036, 9])
```

I would expect to receive a prediction output vector containing 97036 rows. So I proceed to generate my predictions like so

```
test_dataloader = testing.to_dataloader(train=False, batch_size=128 * 10, num_workers=0)
raw_predictions, x = best_tft.predict(testing, mode="raw", return_x=True)
```

However, I receive an output of the size

```
raw_predictions['prediction'].shape
torch.Size([25476, 1, 7])
```

Why are some of these 97036 observations being removed?

Or else, how can I find out which if these 97036 observations are being dropped and why the are being removed?

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of `mode="raw"` in order to get a forecast on the `max_prediction` horizon range.  It is going to give one forecast for each individual row of group and columns of `max_prediction` horizon.

```
torch.Size([25476, 1, 7])
```

This gives one prediction, per one granular group, at a time on the test set, depending on the date range of the test set.

Answer (score 0):

In the source code of the `TimeSeriesDataSet` there are filters to remove short time series. When you set `predict=True` in `TimeSeriesDataSet.from_dataset`, it sets the `min_prediction_length` to `max_prediction_length`. Then, when the actual test dataloader is to be created, all of the time series that are shorter than `min_prediction_length` are removed, which removes the entire data from the testing set, which leaves you with exactly 0 observations. Exactly why it is implemented in this way, I don't know. To make predictions just set:

```
testing = TimeSeriesDataSet.from_dataset(training, df[lambda x: x.year > validation_cutoff], predict=False, stop_randomization=True)
```